# Why wont my vmousedown, vmouseup function work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting this jQuery function to work. I want to use the vmousedown and vmousemove events to work on mobile and although the function works when a mouse is involved, all of the touch events are not responding and thus in mobile nothing happens. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and even when I use the touchmove events, the function still does not work.

```
$("#id").bind( 'vmousedown vmousemove', function( event ) {
  var swipe_y = event.pageY;
   if(swipe_y < 500){
      $('#id').removeClass('example-class');
   }
   else
   $('#id').addClass('example-class');

});
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery Mobile? The virtual flavors of those events are generated by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Yes I have jQuery Mobile included below the jQuery script.

Comment: Try using this instead $("#id").on ( "vmousedown", function( event ) {...